# How does the MyPad iPad app access Facebook Messages, including writing them?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

The Graph API documentation says that the (invite only) message API endpoint is read-only.

The MyPad iPad app allows users to both read and compose messages.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has two APIs at present. The Graph API, which is what all developers should be using, and the REST API which they are in the process of depreciating. While they advise people to use the Graph API, it still lacks features found in the REST API. One of these would appear to be the ability to send messages. Details on the REST API can be found at [their documentation page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/)

Answer (score 0):

Neither graph nor rest API can be used to send inbox messages to any user.
Mypad uses the other way around, which use m.facebook to compose and send(POST) messages directly.
of cos, it requires massive understanding of m. site of facebook. And problem is expected when facebook modify any structure on their m.site one day.